# lmer multilevel regression with intercept constraint

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I regularly have this problem: I want to fit a multilevel regression, with constraint. I don't know how to do that. I usualy end up using `lavaan`, as it allows to set constraints on the regression coefficients. But still it can't have random slope models (only random intercept, and truth is I don't know how to set a constraint on the intercept in `lavaan` either), and I would like to have a multilevel approach.

So basically I have `y` variable having a second order polynomial dependence on `x`, with coefficients depending on the subject `ID`:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.table(x = rep(0:10,5),ID = rep(LETTERS[1:5],each = 11))
df[,a:= rnorm(1,2,1),by = ID]
df[,b:= rnorm(1,1,0.2),by = ID]
df[,y := rnorm(.N,0,10) + a*x + b*x^2 ]

ggplot(df,aes(x,y,color = ID))+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

and I can do normall multilevel:

```
lmer(y ~ x + I(x^2) + (x+ I(x^2)|ID),df)
```

But I would like to constrain the intercept to be 0. Is there a simple way to do so ? 
Thank you

Comment: lmer(y ~ x + I(x^2) + (x+ I(x^2)|ID)  - 1, df) ?

Comment: @user158565 yes, it looks like it is what I was looking for. Do you know how to constrain the coeffs, just in case ?

Comment: Constrain the coef: Example, suppose you want to constrain regression coefficient of x to 3, then generate new response variable by y1 = y - 3*x, fit the model  'lmer(y1 ~  I(x^2) + (x+ I(x^2)|ID),df)'